# URL Amigável não funciona corretamente

Tags: php, htaccess

Sou novo com url amigável, as demais que coloquei funcionam bem mas uma em questão não esta funcionando

```
RewriteRule ^imovel-([0-9]+)\/([a-z]+)\.html$ imovel.php?m=$1&n=$2[NC,L]
```

Na teoria o resultado deveria ser https://www.site.com.br/imovel-1/nome-do-imovel.html, mas da erro 404.

Estou fazendo algo de errado?
Como falei sou iniciante com url amigável.
Obrigado

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Olá!
O trecho ([a-z]+) não contempla sinais de menos.
Adicione o sinal de menos assim: ([a-z-]+)